# Function to group values by jenks in R

Tags: r, grouping

I try to automize my function to create groups. I therefore use `classIntervalls` from the package `classInt` and `cut` from the `base` package. I'd like the style to be "jenks" and the groupsize to be 10 by default. If there are less then 10 `unique` observations i'd like the number of groups to be the number of unique observations. 
So here ist what i tried:

```
set.seed(45)
b=sample(1:50,10)

groupfunction<-function(data,my.style="jenks"){
  ifelse(length(unique(data))<10,tmpbrk<-length(unique(data)),tmpbrk<-10)# tests if the number of unique values is bigger than 10
  tmp<-classIntervals(data,tmpbrk,my.style,unique=T) #find the intervalls
  tmp<-cut(data,tmp$brks,dig.lab=20,include.lowest = T) #cut the data by the breaks from the intervalls
  tmp<-as.character(tmp) #turn results into characters to substitute unwanted characters
  tmp<-gsubfn(".",list("["="",","="-",")"="","("=""," "="","]"=""),tmp) # substitute unwanted characters
}

groupfunction(b)
```

but I get an error message: Error in cut.default(data, tmp$brks, dig.lab = 20, include.lowest = T) : 'breaks' are not unique.

I know what this error message means. But can anyone help me to implement this function and get it work. I already heard about `cut2` but I'm not sure if I can implement it with jenks.

Comment: Should use `if(.){.}else{.}`. Then you only get an unsurprising warning since your vector has only unique values.

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it work with some minor acomodations to the code.

```
groupfunction<-function(data,my.style="jenks"){
  ifelse(length(unique(data))<11,tmpbrk<-length(unique(data))-1,tmpbrk<-10)# tests if the number of unique values is bigger than 10
  tmp<-classIntervals(data,tmpbrk,style=my.style) #find the intervalls
  tmp<-cut(data,unique(tmp$brks),dig.lab=20,include.lowest = T) #cut the data by the breaks from the intervalls
  tmp<-as.character(tmp) #turn results into characters to substitute unwanted characters
  tmp<-gsubfn(".",list("["="",","="-",")"="","("=""," "="","]"=""),tmp) # substitute unwanted characters
}
```

so what it actually does is that it that it takes the data, controls the length of unique values and checks if it is smaller than eleven. If so it takes the length of unique values -1 and applies this as the number of breaks to built up the jenks. Jenks then are built upon unique values. 
The function works on single vectors or whole dataframes but can slow down the pc depending on speed and the size of the df.